# Is "the phenomenon that a conductor experiences a force in a magnetic field" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, independent-clauses

The full sentence is:

> [The Motor Effect is:] The phenomenon that a current-carrying
>   conductor experiences a force in an external magnetic field.

My Physics teacher says that it sounds clunky.

I can find a similar usage on a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein's_example):

> Stein's example... is the phenomenon that when three or more parameters are estimated simultaneously, there exist combined estimators more accurate on average ... than any method that handles the parameters separately.

The argument against this is that there is the "when" placing a condition upon the rest of the sentence. I disagree and believe that "The phenomenon that " + an independent clause is perfectly valid grammar.

Comment: _Experience_ is a verb that requires a sentient (normally human) subject: _He experienced the effect personally_. One doesn't speak of inanimate objects like wires "experiencing" anything. Particularly when the "experience" is undetectable by unaided human senses.

Comment: I concur with John Lawler; and that aside, 'valid' grammar is not necessarily 'non-clunky' grammar. The usual complement to *phenomenon* is an *of* PP: see (for what it's worth) [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+phenomenon+of%2Cthe+phenomenon+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20phenomenon%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20phenomenon%20that%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I see no problem with _experiences_, but the _that_ does make the sentence sound clunky, and, I suspect, ungrammatical. Replace "that" with "whereby" and you'll be golden: _[...] the phenomenon whereby a current-carrying conductor experiences a force [...]_.

Comment: Definitely agree with Dan's suggestion, it makes it so much clearer. Would accept it as the answer if I could. I disagree with John though, as an accepted definition of "experience" is "to encounter or undergo and event or occurrence" which is clearly the context in which it is being used here.

Comment: @JohnLawler regarding *experience* - I think that horse has already bolted. Particularly in the case of force fields and actions-at-a-distance, *experience* has long been used this way. Aerodynamics also uses it this way (probably do to similar math, albeit different physics). Less acceptable is its use in ordinary Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: Would consider "a phenomenon wherein an external magnetic field exerts a force on a current-carrying conductor".

Comment: I would use "in which" rather than "that".